# jquery addressing an id with space

Tags: jquery

I have a problem to modify a block which sent to a iFrame, so I try to use jQuery to modify it after documentReady, my problem is that the id of the div contain spaces: I want to change the text and add an image

How could I do it with jQuery ?

```
<div id="Cash On Delivery" data-pm="Cash On Delivery">
 <div class="nameRow">
  <div class="methodIcon"> /* here I want to place a pic */</div>
  <div class="methodName">Cash On Delivery</div> <!--this I want to change-->
   <div class="paymentMethodDetails right">
   <div class="checkMark"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ids cannot have space.  It goes against the web standard. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute  *When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's tree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any ASCII whitespace.*

Comment: but this is what the 3rd part generated. its a code in and iFrame

Comment: Might need to go the route of accessing it by it's data attribute.

Comment: @IsmailBerlin: Then you need to tell the 3rd party they're generating broken HTML.

Answer (score 2):

`id` values must not contain a space. It's almost [the only limitation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) they have.

Although you *may* be able to access that element with an attribute selector:

```
var methodIcon = $("[id='Cash On Delivery'] .methodIcon");
var methodName = $("[id='Cash On Delivery'] .methodName");
```

Example:

```js
var methodIcon = $("[id='Cash On Delivery'] .methodIcon");
var methodName = $("[id='Cash On Delivery'] .methodName");
methodIcon.text("pic goes here");
methodName.text("new method name here");
```

```html
<div id="Cash On Delivery" data-pm="Cash On Delivery">
 <div class="nameRow">
  <div class="methodIcon"></div>
  <div class="methodName">Cash On Delivery</div> <!--this I want to change-->
   <div class="paymentMethodDetails right">
   <div class="checkMark"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

....it would be much better to stick to a valid `id` instead.

Answer (score 1):

id should not have spaces but if you want to target that id in jquery use this :

```
$("div[id='Cash On Delivery']");
```